# Using jQuery how can I make an div object visible using a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following div is part of my body:

```
   <div id="errorSection" class="alert alert-danger"> Error: Location could not be found.</div>
    <br>
```

I have this div styled as follows:

```
  #errorSection{
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 14pt;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
```

How can I make this appear using jQuery when calling the following function. The way I have it now is calling an error.

```
  function noLocation(){
    $('#errorSection').style.visibility.visible;
  }
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: $('#errorSection').show () will do the work

Comment: @MohdAsimSuhail No it won't [jQuery.show()](https://api.jquery.com/show/). That's only for `display: none;`

Comment: Here's a quote from the API: [jQuery.show](https://api.jquery.com/show/) "is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "block" )`, except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a `display` value of `inline`, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed `inline`."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping your declared CSS would be:

```
$('#errorSection').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

But I'd advise you to use an extra CSS declaration like this:

```css
#errorSection.showError {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```js
$('#errorSection').addClass('showError');
```

This means you can change your CSS in the future to use `display: none;` (or even `height: 0;` or `position: absolute; left: -99999;`) and not have to modify your JavaScript (Separation of concerns)

Comment: Agreed, either way would work but adding and removing or toggling a class is much cleaner with a separate CSS block or stylesheet controlling the CSS.

Comment: Thank you as well. Good idea with toggling classes

Comment: @ClosDesign You beat me to editing my brain spasm ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Simple.  You are mixing straight Javascript and jQuery, which does not work. 
If using the 'visibility' property and not the 'display'

You should do.

```
function noLocation(){
   $('#errorSection').css("visibility", "visible");
}
```

or

```
function noLocation(){
    $('#errorSection').css({"visibility": "visible", "text-align": "center",
"font-style": "bold"}); //can use comma delimited properties like in a css file sheet in the {} brackets.
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. The first answer worked but the second did not work for me. I got an error about unexpected {

Comment: @Peter, I updated the second one with the multiple properties. I was incorrect the first time. I had to look it up again. Should be updated. I also like DJDaveMark's answer too with removing and adding or toggling a class name instead.  This way your CSS is separate from your JS.

Answer (score 0):

Different ways in jQuery, couple of them below:

1) Use of `css` function

- Show: `$('#errorSection').css("display", "inline")` different values can be here like `inline, block, inline-block`
- Hide:  `$('#errorSection').css("display", "none")`

2) Or you can use `show` and `hide`

- Show: `$('#errorSection').show()`
- Hide: `$('#errorSection').hide()`

3) Having css class and you can toggle to make show/hide effect:

```
 .error {
    display: inline; #or whatever like block, inline-block based on your design 
  }
```

Show/Hide can be triggered using:

`$('#errorSection').toggleClass( "error" );`

Comment: He'd need to change his CSS though. `visibility: hidden;` might be exactly what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

The visibility issue has been dealt with in other posts and personally I would add / remove a class like @DJDaveMark suggests, but there is a built in toggle function in jquery that is useful- so this is to provide an alternative: simply start out with the element hidden, and then on the click of the button - use toggle() to toggle the display.

I have used a named function so that you can easily use this in your existing code, but you can just as easily put the toggle into the click handler of an element like the button that I have put in here.

```js
$('#togglevisibility').click(function(){
 toggleVisibility();
})

function toggleVisibility() {
 $('#errorSection').toggle();
}
```

```css
#errorSection{
    display:none;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: 14pt;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="togglevisibility">Click Me To Toggle Visibility</button>
<hr/>

<div id="errorSection" class="alert alert-danger"> Error: Location could not be found.</div>
```

Comment: I thought about using jQuery.toggleClass but because it's an error message, he'll want to show it in one part of his code, then hide it elsewhere. You'd also want to avoid hiding the message if the user provokes the same error twice!